# Use Flask to convert a Pandas dataframe to CSV and serve a download

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I have a Pandas dataframe in my Flask app that I want to return as a CSV file.

```
return Response(df.to_csv())
```

The problem is that the output appears in the browser instead of downloading as a separate file. How can I change that?

I tried the following as well but it just gave empty output.

```
response = make_response(df.to_csv())
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
return Response(response)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Set the `Content-Disposition` to tell the browser to download the file instead of showing its content on the page.

```
resp = make_response(df.to_csv())
resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
return resp
```

Comment: Can I choose a filename?

Comment: filename = name_you_want + ".csv"
...
```headers={
                        "Content-Disposition": "attachment;"
                        "filename={}".format(filename_you_want)
                    }```

Comment: Can I add text to this response to show on the app.route like "your file has been downloaded"

Comment: Is there anyway i can return multiple csv files?

Comment: @Hamzausmanghani, that i don't know, sorry)

Comment: @MaxU I did it using zip file. [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67175581/using-flask-to-return-multiple-dataframes-as-csv#comment118738937_67175581)

Answer (score 13):

This is pretty much the same solution but you can just pass the same info into Response:

```py
return Response(
       df.to_csv(),
       mimetype="text/csv",
       headers={"Content-disposition":
       "attachment; filename=filename.csv"})
```

Answer (score 5):

set the content-disposition and use stringIO to convert dataframe to stream, below is the code to achieve,

```
execel_file = StringIO.StringIO()
filename = "%s.csv" % ('output file')
df.to_csv(execel_file, encoding='utf-8')
csv_output = execel_file.getvalue()
execel_file.close()

resp = make_response(csv_output)
resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = ("attachment; filename=%s" % filename)
resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
return resp
```