# Using flask to return multiple dataframes as csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, flask

I've **multiple** dataframes and i want to return **multiple** downloadable CSV files using flask.

I tried following code but it can only return **one** downloadable CSV file.

```
resp = make_response(df.to_csv())
resp.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/csv"
return resp
```

I tried to return multiple responses (`return resp1, resp2`) but got following error:

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not Response
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: You cannot do that with only flask. Either you zip the files and return one file. Or you need to write frontend javascript code that does downloads them all.

Comment: @Tristan I tried it using zip file and its worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my answer, Actually there is **no way to return all files at once using flask only** so i made a zip file containing all CSVs and then returned it.

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('main_code/output.zip', 'w') as csv_zip:
    csv_zip.writestr("data1.csv", data1.to_csv())
    csv_zip.writestr("data2.csv", data2.to_csv())

return send_file('output.zip',
                 mimetype='zip',
                 attachment_filename='output.zip',
                 as_attachment=True)
```