# how to create a download api endpoint in djangorestframework for a csv file I am writing into after consuming data from a world weather online api's

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am consuming a weather api endpoint from HTTPS:https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx and my views.py logic looks like this

```
class HistoricalWeatherView(APIView):
    """Gets Historical Weather of a location"""

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        url = 'https://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx'


        param = request.query_params
        query_param = {
            'key': 'my_api_key',
            'q': param.get('location'),
            'format': 'json',    
            'tp': 24,
            'date': param.get('startdate'),
            'enddate':  param.get('enddate'),
            'includelocation': 'yes'
        }
                
        weather_data =  requests.get(url, params=query_param).json()
        output = len(weather_data['data']['weather'])
        final_weather = []
        output_csv = 'historical_weather.csv'
        for result in range(output):
            final= {
                
                'country': weather_data.get('data').get('nearest_area')[0].get('country')[0]['value'],
                'areaName': weather_data.get('data').get('nearest_area')[0].get('areaName')[0]['value'],                
                'date': weather_data.get('data').get('weather')[result].get('date'),
                'max_temperature': weather_data.get('data').get('weather')[result].get('maxtempC'),
                'min_temperature': weather_data.get('data').get('weather')[result].get('mintempC'),
                'indicator': weather_data.get('data').get('weather')[result].get('hourly')[0].get('weatherDesc')[0].get('value'),
                'Humidity': weather_data.get('data').get('weather')[result].get('hourly')[0].get('humidity'),
                'cloud_over': weather_data.get('data').get('weather')[result].get('hourly')[0].get('cloudcover'),
                'windspeed': weather_data.get('data').get('weather')[result].get('hourly')[0].get('windspeedKmph'),
                'precipitation': weather_data.get('data').get('weather')[result].get('hourly')[0].get('precipInches')    
            }
            final_weather.append(final)
        df_weather = pd.DataFrame(final_weather)
        df_weather.to_csv(output_csv, index=False)

        return Response(final_weather, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

it generates the csv_file but I want to be able to create an endpoint where it can be downloaded to download folder
localhost:8000/api/weather/history/download

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38634862/use-flask-to-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-and-serve-a-download

Comment: thank you so much I am reading this but where can I get the documentation so I can read in depth about it

Answer (score 1):

I think Django file response can work for you.

```
 from django.http import FileResponse
 response = FileResponse(open('myfile.png', 'rb'))
 return respose
```

you can more info here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/

Comment: You can also find an example at https://www.javatpoint.com/django-csv-output

Comment: thanks for this. I my overriding djangorestframework response

Comment: Kindly let me know if it works for you or accepts the solution.

Comment: it works but it is downloading the whole page and not the csv file

Comment: I want to be able to return both the response dictionary and a download version

Comment: For that, you should generate two API calls asynchronously from the front end then handle both of them separately in the backend one for each purpose.